powershellとの連携について
設定作業を行ったPCに対し、EmEditorとpowershellスクリプトで操作しテキスト値とレジストリのバイナリ値の整合を取りたいのですが、そのような動作は可能なのでしょうか。

「整合を取りたい」の部分をより具体的に記述してください。

例えばこんな風 【PowerShell】レジストリの値をコマンドで確認する［reg query/Get-Item/Get-ItemProperty］ に情報が取得できるでしょうが、それでは不足なのか、あとは具体的にはそれらを使って何をしようとしているのか、細かい手順を追記してみてはどうでしょう？

EmEditor が出てくるのは恐らく差分をチェックしようとしているのかと思いますが、一方で「整合性を取る」は一般的に「違いがあったら正す」意味で使われます。なので、(質問として) 何をどこまで求めているのかが正確に読み取れません。

コメントありがとうございます
あくまで例なのですが、タスクバーの表示アイコンを設定するとレジストリのHKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Classes\Local Settings\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\TrayNotifyにあるIconSteams並びにPastIconsStreamが変更されますが、バイナリ値で保存されている為、powershellのスクリプトだけでは設定されている内容の期待値と同一になっているかが確認できない状態です。
ですのでEmEditorを使用しバイナリ値からテキスト値に変更しpowershellスクリプトで同一になっているかの確認または、テキスト値からバイナリ値へ変更し同一になっているかの動作が可能かが知りたいです。

ちょっと古い記事ですが、もしかしたらあまり意味の無いことをやろうとしているのかもしれませんね。通知領域のアイコン情報のレジストリについて バイナリ値になっていて個別の内容は分からないと思います。, Win 10編: 通知履歴をクリーニングする 各アプリケーションのアイコン情報などを保持するデータベースであろうバイナリ値「AppDB」を削除することでチューニングに成功しました。, 「タスクバーに表示するアイコンを選択します」以下に残るアンインストール済みアプリケーションの残骸を消す

設定を行った内容をpowershellを使用して確認しているのですが、タスクバーの表示アイコンの様にレジストリ内にバイナリ値で保存されている物はpowershellだけでは確認ができない為、バイナリ値をテキスト値に変換できるツールを使用する事により確認できるようになるのではないかと思い質問させていただいております。

レジストリのREG_BINARYのデータ内容を文字列で得るだけなら、regコマンドのreg queryを使えば出来るでしょう。同様の概要記事。reg query 標準出力に出てくるのでそれを取得して加工すれば良いと思われます。

知識不足で申し訳ありません。reg queryでREG_BINARYのデータ内容を確認しようとしてもバイナリ値で取得されてしまう為、正しく動作しない様に思われます。
例としてですが、タスクバーの表示アイコンをMicrosoft Teams、Microsoft Outiookのみに変更をしpowershellのreg queryコマンドで検索をかけMicrosoft Teams、Microsoft Outiookが存在しているかわかりませんでした。
この場合、検索する値をレジストリ値に変換し検索、もしくは検索したREG_BINARYをテキスト値に変換するしか方法が無いのではないでしょうか

@toshihiro さん、何か理解不足か認識の不一致があるようです。先にコメントで強調したようにバイナリ値になっていて個別の内容は分からないと思います。ですね。なので取得出来るのは16進数文字列で表現されたバイナリデータだけでしょう。逆に対象レジストリの値がどんな構造になっていて何を表すのか説明している公開資料とかあるのなら、それを提示してもらった方が良いでしょう。ちなみにもうあまり意味が有るとは思えませんが、確認したいテキスト値とはどんな内容か、それは何のプログラムがどんな時に表示するのか、といった情報を質問に追記すると、何かのヒントを答えてくれる人が居るかもしれませんね。

色々と関連しそうな機能があるので、探ってみては？ ToastNotificationHistory クラス, 通知と通知領域, Windowsの通知センターの内容を取得する(通知リスナー), Windowsプッシュ通知サービス(WNS)..., ...(WNS) overview
